# Xor swap code vs temporary variable swap code in java

Tags: java

I recently found out about xor swap code.

```
a^=b;
b^=a;
a^=b;
```

I know this works only for Integer types.

I also heard that this is faster compared to the temporary variable swap in java. If it is faster why doesn't anyone use them?

Comment: Where did you "hear that it was faster"?  (It almost certainly isn't; if it were, the JVM would optimize it for you.)

Comment: The performance gains are going to be beyond negligible when compared to the readability loss. Assuming that there are any performance gains at all, which I am doubtful of.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit harder to understand for a new person reading your code. We prefer the code that provides us meaning as in first sight. That's why we don`t use this.
We have another strategy of swapping variable same like above with only arithmetic operators given below:

```
a = a+b;
b = a-b;
a = a-b;
```

Again, this does not provides that much readability that we get using third variable.

Comment: Isn't this having more problems??? What if a is an integer and has a max value of 2,147,483,647 and if b is an integer with any value. Won't the values overflow?

Comment: Didn`t get. Problem in what sense? @ShashankSJ

Comment: Try the swap you suggested with a= 2147483647 and b =2. The numbers won't get swapped. The end results show that the numbers are totally changed

Comment: It is working fine with these values also. I have just tried it. You can see this in this picture. https://github.com/unknownboyy/images/blob/master/Capture3.PNG